# How to verify all correct input digits C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code, this can check if the input is an integer; however, if something like '5o' is input it still flows through, can someone help me make sure all the digits input into x are correct, thank you!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << "enter x please: ";
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  while (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "sorry wrong input, try again: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> x;
  }
  cout << "correct input!";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do me a favor: when the input is wrong, give an explanatory message ! (even better to give explanations in the initial question)

Comment: You can read the input into a string, and loop over the characters to check if all of them are numbers. Don't forget to check for the sign (if there can be one): the first character can be not just a number, but also '+' or '-'.

Comment: Read the input as a string, check the string matches your definition of a number, convert the string to a number. This is the only bullet proof approach to input validation.

Comment: It surprises me how often code like the above is recommended as the way to do input validation when, as your question demonstrates, it doesn't work completely.

Comment: `cin >> x` succeeds if there is at least one valid character to consume. When you type `5o`, there is one valid character to consume, so `cin >> x` consumes it and succeeds. If you want a *line* of input that contains a number and nothing else, you need to (1) read a *line* and (2) validate that it contains a number and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read an entire line at once as a string and validate:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::printf("Enter x: ");
    
    std::string line;

    while (true) 
    {
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, line))
        {
            std::puts("Stream failed."); // Not much we can do
            return -1;
        }

        if (std::all_of(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), std::isdigit))
            break;
        else
            std::printf("Input is not a number. Try again: ");
    }
    int const x = std::stoi(line);
    std::printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```